# understanding R performance plyr - dply and Factor variables

Tags: r, plyr

My computer is an Intel Core i7, 12GB RAM and Windows 10, just to give you some context. I am trying to execute a simple operation over a dataframe, the dataframe has around **41K**  **entries** and its size in `.csv` format is around 20MB.
The dataframe has 4 columns:

1. Adress: **Factor** variable with around **41K** different levels (no repeated levels)
2. Block: **Factor** variable with around **39K** different levels (most of the Blocks have only one address related to them but others have up to a 100
3. Energy: An int variable
4. Segment: **Factor** variable with only **7** levels

Let me show you the `summary()` output of the dataFrame:

```
         Address            Block           ENERGY        Segment     
 BAC0602532301:    1   A33093097:  165   Min.   :      0   A   :11863  
 BAC0603557493:    1   B79083796:  165   1st Qu.:  48590   A+  : 7723  
 BAC0604416292:    1   A08721177:  158   Median :  75420   A++ : 3948  
 BAE0602962660:    1   A46581666:  153   Mean   : 144694   A+++: 2324  
 BAE0603336589:    1   B21053848:  138   3rd Qu.: 154167   B   : 8110  
 BAI0602739803:    1   A08119687:   89   Max.   :2802501   C   : 4051  
 (Other)      :40086   (Other)  :39224                     D   : 2073
```

Now, the operation I want to perform is **for every Block** (there are around 39K) select the **maximum value of the ENERGY** column and the **Address** and **Segement** related to this **ENERGY**.

So to do this I know there are many different options. I usually try to use functions from the `plyr` or `dplyr` packages because I think they are faster than other options of the Basic package specially if the operation can be thought as an Split-Appy-Combine operation.
The problem is that if I execute this from `plyr` package:

```
 ddply(dataFrame, "Block", summarize, AddressMax =  Address[which.max(ENERGY)], SegmentMax = Segment[which.max(ENERGY)], EnergyMax = max(ENERGY))
```

**The computer never ends and I have to end up killing the R program**

If I execute this from the `dply` package:

```
Blocks <- group_by(DataFrame,Blocks)

MaxsbyBlock <- summarise(Blocks, AdressMax = Address[which.max(ENERGY)], SegmentMax = Segment[which.max(ENERGY)], EnergyMax = max(ENERGY))
```

**It takes around 30 to 40 seconds to finish (at least it finishes!!!).**

Otherwise if I give up trying to recover the Address using **ddply** it works perfectly, in fact if you execute this (notice that now the AdressMax is gone):

```
ddply(dataFrame, "Block", summarize,SegmentMax = Segment[which.max(ENERGY)], EnergyMax = max(ENERGY))
```

**It takes around 3 to 4 seconds to finish.** The `ddply` strategy improves even more. So, **could someone tell me of give some insight of what is the problem trying to recover the value of the Adress Factor variable using ddply or the `dply` package? If you use the __aggregate** function and **merge** it is much more faster and I would like to understand at least a little bit why:

```
aggdata<-aggregate(Energy~Blocks, data=dataFrame, max)
merge(aggdata,dataFrame,by.x=c('Blocks','Energy'),by.y=c('Blocks','Energy'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that this Q hasn't been answered or commented on for 5 days now.

I have no explanation why the `plyr` and `dplyr` approaches don't perform as expected but if the OP is interested in solving the underlying problem, here are two approaches using `data.table`.

### Benchmarking three approaches

With the dummy data `DT` created below, three different approaches are being benchmarked:

- `base_agg_merge`: aggregate and merge using base functions as given in the Q
- `dt_agg_merge`: aggregate and join using `data.table`
- `dt_order_group`: order and group using `data.table`

The other approaches from the Q needed too much run-time (`dplyr`: 22 secs, `plyr` without `AddressMax`: 2.6 secs) so they were omitted from the `microbenchmark` run.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
  base_agg_merge = {
    aggdata <- aggregate(Energy ~ Block, data = DT, max)
    result1 <- merge(aggdata, DT, by = c("Block", "Energy"))
  },
  dt_agg_merge = {
    temp <- DT[, .(max_Energy = max(Energy)), keyby = Block]
    result2 <- DT[temp, on = c("Block", Energy = "max_Energy")]
  },
  dt_order_group = {
    result3 <- DT[order(-Energy), .SD[1], keyby = Block]
  },
  times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 base_agg_merge 275.106516 279.646932 297.287758 281.229186 302.062803 395.936697    10
   dt_agg_merge   7.527084   7.789126   9.489412   9.001351   9.342873  17.171266    10
 dt_order_group   4.458858   5.437927   6.508181   6.784382   7.405881   8.685504    10
```

The fastest approach `dt_order_group` works as follows:

- order by `Energy` (reversed)
- group by `Block`
- return first row in each group

Although `base_agg_merge` and `dt_agg_merge` follow the same idea, the `data.table` version is 30 times faster:

- group by `Block`
- get `max(Energy)` for each group
- merge on `Block` and `max_Energy` (note, this should return any ties, i.e., rows with the same `max_Energy` in a group as well)

The benchmark was run on a PC with Intel Core i5, 8 GB RAM, Windows 10 using R version 3.3.1 and the development version 1.9.7 of `data.table` (see [Installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation))

### Data

The OP has given a `summary()` of the underlying data which was very helpful in modeling dummy data.

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 41000L
m <- 10000L
dataFrame <- data.frame(
  Address = factor(m + sample.int(n)),
  Block = factor(m + sample.int(39000L, n, replace = TRUE, prob = 1/seq_len(39000L))),
  Energy = as.integer(rlnorm(n, meanlog = 11)),
  Segment = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:7], n, replace = TRUE))
)
summary(dataFrame)
##     Address          Block           Energy        Segment 
##  10001  :    1   10001  : 3714   Min.   :   1294   A:5871  
##  10002  :    1   10002  : 1849   1st Qu.:  30579   B:5762  
##  10003  :    1   10003  : 1247   Median :  59730   C:5836  
##  10004  :    1   10004  :  905   Mean   :  99107   D:5892  
##  10005  :    1   10005  :  719   3rd Qu.: 117060   E:5855  
##  10006  :    1   10006  :  584   Max.   :2977127   F:5979  
##  (Other):40994   (Other):31982                     G:5805
```

Except `Energy` all columns are factors.